# Is there an automated way to generate CRUD templates on django Project/App

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, command-line-interface

I'm new in django, and it seems as it says batteries included FW, and I was wondering if this feature is available in django to generate CRUD templates for each entity using CLI.. like

Python manage.py createCrud books, Member

This might include the urls, views etc

Is there something like that.. or maybe a plugin can do this?

I haven't yet resulted something valuable.
Expecting python code or plugin installation then super-tuning

Comment: You should try: https://github.com/Solvosoft/django-gentelella-widgets or the simple Django Admin panel.